# Unexpected error in sorted() method on tuples python 3

Tags: python, pandas

I'm dealing with a problem I really can't **see** why it's happening.
I have a column of tuples from a dataframe and I copy it to an object(thus, it becomes a Series object).

The tuples are made ALL OF THEM by (number/ID, "[]") (Example Below):

```
(288784, '[]')
(289120, '[]')
(289353, '[]')
(289736, '[]')
(289769, '[]')
(289819, '[]')
(290187, '[]')
(290219, '[]')
(290266, '[]')
(290305, '[]')
```

but when I do the following:

```
dictionary = dict(itertools.zip_longest(partial_data_frame["ID"], partial_data_frame[columnName]))
 partial_data_frame[columnName+"_tuple"] = dictionary.items()
 sorted_list = partial_data_frame[columnName+"_tuple"].sort(inplace=False)
 sorted_list = sorted(sorted_list,key=operator.itemgetter(1)) #to order by the 2nd value of tuple
```

I receive the "TypeError: float() < str()".
How is that possible? even though I have the same string all over the column.

Comment: It might help to add the code that generates the tuples

Comment: @jamesmf I think this question would be off-topic here, even if it is made more clear.

Comment: I agree, unless the error is specific to dataframes, which might justify it. Otherwise I agree it's better posted elsewhere.

Comment: The error is more about python sorting sorted() method but I'm using it to data analysis, I thought here would fit better, @jamesmf .

Comment: In that case I agree that it might be better elsewhere

Comment: Could you tell me where? I'm really out of solutions for the problem.

Comment: @FelipeBormann  StackOverflow would be best suited for your question

Comment: It's going to be really hard to answer this without an example data set. On the surface, the error seems straightforward: it's that somewhere in the new column, you have a float and a string being compared, which implies that they're in the same position of two different records (e.g. one tuple has a first element of `2.0` and another has a first element of `'3.0'`, string). Do you have some clear reason to think this is not the case?

Comment: @DavidZ I know I can't compare them but the problem is: somehow in a list of tuples were all first elements are integers and the second are the strings "[]" (Yes, I've checked them all). A sample of my dataset is: (2,[]), (3,[]),(4,[]), (5,[]) and I'm using the code above to sort them by the second value of the tuple.